# What is the easiest way to make half nested circles?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 circles and I wanna them half-circles like below

[image]

When I try to make them half here what happens below

I don't know why, this is how it works when I tried below, I added them border-top-left-radius and border-top-right-radius to make all of them half circles but only first one worked the others shifted to the right as you can see. Is there another way to make this implementation easier?

[image]

```css
#first-circle {
   border-bottom: 0 !important;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-top-left-radius: 401px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 401px !important
 }
 #second-circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom: 0 !important;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   border-top-left-radius: 301px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 301px !important
   margin: -150px 0px 0px -150px;
 }

 #third-circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom: 0 !important;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   top: 50%;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   left: 50%;
   border-top-left-radius: 201px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 201px !important
   margin: -100px 0px 0px -100px;
 }
 #fourth-circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom: 0 !important;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   border-top-left-radius: 101px !important;
   border-top-right-radius: 101px !important
   margin: -50px 0px 0px -50px;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="first-circle">
            <div id="second-circle" >
                <div id="third-circle" >
                  <div id="fourth-circle" >
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: TBH, I'd use an SVG for this instead of trying to abuse CSS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use transform:

```css
.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}
.position-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
.half-circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.half-circle:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(.8);
}
.half-circle:nth-child(3) {
  transform: scale(.6);
}
.half-circle:nth-child(4) {
  transform: scale(.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="position-relative">
  <div class="half-circle position-absolute"></div>
  <div class="half-circle position-absolute"></div>
  <div class="half-circle position-absolute"></div>
  <div class="half-circle position-absolute"></div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can change width and height of every circles and position them accordingly:

```css
.position-relative {
      position: relative;
      height: 100px;
    }
    .position-absolute {
      position: absolute;
    }
    .half-circle {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        border-top-left-radius: 100px;
        border-top-right-radius: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transform-origin: center bottom;
    }
    .half-circle:nth-child(2) {
      width: 180px;
      height: 90px;
      border-top-left-radius: 90px;
      border-top-right-radius: 90px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 10px;
    }
    .half-circle:nth-child(3) {
      width: 160px;
      height: 80px;
      border-top-left-radius: 80px;
      border-top-right-radius: 80px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 20px;
    }
    .half-circle:nth-child(4) {
      width: 140px;
      height: 70px;
      border-top-left-radius: 70px;
      border-top-right-radius: 70px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="position-relative">
      <div class="half-circle position-absolute"></div>
      <div class="half-circle position-absolute"></div>
      <div class="half-circle position-absolute"></div>
      <div class="half-circle position-absolute"></div>
    </div>
```

**PS:** To nest the circle, we don't necessarily need to nest html as well. Simple markup can be used like above. Also, if you don't use bootstrap-4 then you can remove position-relative, position-absolute classes and then give style on them.

Comment: The thickness of the circles also changes with `scale` though.

Comment: Ah, then you can decrease width and height and then translate

Comment: I would also refrain from adding more classes than needed. If you give the half circle the position:absolute, you can drop a class. And then rename the relative to a 'half-circle-wrapper' and give that absolute. IMO your now just inline styling, but with classes :)

Comment: @Martijn I have used it for future visitors who use bootstrap-4 and we don't manually write position rule in the stylesheet.

Comment: But now you've made it a bootstrap answer, instead of a generic one. Isnt this the same as providing a jquery answer where normal JS would suffice just as well? :)

Comment: Most  of us  use bootstrap-4 and that's why. If anyone who doesn't use bootstrap then I expect they would change those class and write  accordingly. Anyways, I've made it clarification on the note.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really easy, using `border-radius:50%;`, `display:flex;`, and `overflow:hidden;`:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; font-size:0; /* set font individually due to white space */
}
html,body{
  background:#000; margin:0;
}
#container{
  width:400px; height:200px; background:#fff; overflow:hidden;
}
#container div{
  display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid #000; overflow:hidden;
}
#first-circle{
  width:400px; height:400px; background:blue; 
}
#second-circle{
  width:300px; height:300px; background:red;
}
#third-circle{
  width:200px; height:200px; background:orange;
}
#fourth-circle{
  width:100px; height:100px; background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='first-circle'>
    <div id='second-circle'>
      <div id='third-circle'>
        <div id='fourth-circle'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need:

Keep decreasing these 2

```
 `width: 200px;
  height: 100px;`
```

in my case it is height is half of width and that should give you your desired output.

> NOTE: If you want to increase the width and height of the circle then you may have to tweak the `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` as well.

```css
.half-circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.second-circle {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.third-circle {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.fourth-circle {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle">
  <div class="second-circle">
    <div class="third-circle">
      <div class="fourth-circle"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the circles share alot of similar css you should use some classes to make the code more readable.

To achieve what you wanted you need to make sure each circle's height is 50% of its width, because it is a half circle!

After that you just need to align all elements to the bottom and center them up. Easiest way to center an absolutely positioned element is using `left` and `transform: translateX`.

```css
.half-circle {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 400px;
    border-top-right-radius: 400px;
}

.inner {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#first-circle {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

#second-circle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}

#third-circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

#fourth-circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-circle" class="half-circle">
    <div id="second-circle" class="half-circle inner">
        <div id="third-circle" class="half-circle inner">
            <div id="fourth-circle" class="half-circle inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can move the radius props to the `.half-circle` class. If you have a radius of 500px; for them, the smaller once will still behave correct. It just has to match/be larger than the largest circle. Saves 6 lines of code :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your css.

First you missed some semicolons, the rest was trial and error:

height half of the widht

top margin -50, -25, 0

```
#first-circle {
   border-bottom: 0 !important;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-top-left-radius: 401px !important;
   border-top-right-radius: 401px !important;
 }
 #second-circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom: 0 !important;
   width: 300px;
   height: 150px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   border-top-left-radius: 301px !important;
   border-top-right-radius: 301px !important;
   margin: -50px 0px 0px -150px;
 }

 #third-circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom: 0 !important;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   top: 50%;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   left: 50%;
   border-top-left-radius: 201px !important;
   border-top-right-radius: 201px !important;
   margin: -25px 0px 0px -100px;
 }
 #fourth-circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom: 0 !important;
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   border-top-left-radius: 101px !important;
   border-top-right-radius: 101px !important;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px -50px;
 }
```

Comment: `!important` isn't needed. It never should, but in this case it isnt :)

Comment: @Martijn: it wasn't me! ;-)

Comment: But it is *your* answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this using only one element:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  display:inline-flex;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:2px solid;
  border-bottom:transparent;
  border-radius:1000px 1000px 0 0;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,transparent 75%,#000 calc(75% + 1px) calc(75% + 2px),transparent calc(75% + 3px)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,transparent 50%,#000 calc(40% + 1px) calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,transparent 25%,#000 calc(25% + 1px) calc(25% + 2px),transparent calc(25% + 3px));
}

.box::before {
  content:"";
  padding-top:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:200px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a gradient for this, and not elements. In order to "capsulate" the border, you need to add end point for the first white area and a start point for the second white area (--fill-color).

To avoid blurryness if increasing the border width (--border-thickness), you need to add a start and end values to create a range for the color. I showcased how that can be done in the first blue circle.

```css
div { /* mostly for show */
   height: 50vw;
   background-color: grey;
}

.circles-background {
  --fill-color: white;
  --border-thickness: 2px;
  --half-border-thickness: calc(var(--border-thickness) / 2);
  --circles-sizes: 12%;
  --border-color: #121212;
  
  --first-circle-border-color:  blue;
  --first-border-start:     calc(var(--circles-sizes) - var(--half-border-thickness));
  --first-border-end:       calc(var(--circles-sizes) + var(--half-border-thickness));
  
  --second-circle-border-color: red;
  --second-border-start:    calc(2 * var(--circles-sizes) - var(--half-border-thickness));
  --second-border-position: calc(2 * var(--circles-sizes));
  --second-border-end:      calc(2 * var(--circles-sizes) + var(--half-border-thickness));
  
  --third-circle-border-color:  var(--border-color);
  --third-border-start:     calc(3 * var(--circles-sizes) - var(--half-border-thickness));
  --third-border-position:  calc(3 * var(--circles-sizes));
  --third-border-end:       calc(3 * var(--circles-sizes) + var(--half-border-thickness));
  
  --fourth-circle-border-color: purple;
  --fourth-border-start:    calc(4 * var(--circles-sizes) - var(--half-border-thickness));
  --fourth-border-position: calc(4 * var(--circles-sizes));
  --fourth-border-end:      calc(4 * var(--circles-sizes) + var(--half-border-thickness));
  
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom,
    var(--fill-color)                 var(--first-border-start),
    var(--first-circle-border-color)  var(--first-border-start),
    var(--first-circle-border-color)  var(--first-border-end),
    var(--fill-color)                 var(--first-border-end),

    var(--fill-color)                 var(--second-border-start),
    var(--second-circle-border-color) var(--second-border-position),
    var(--fill-color)                 var(--second-border-end),
    
    var(--fill-color)                 var(--third-border-start),
    var(--third-circle-border-color)  var(--third-border-position),
    var(--fill-color)                 var(--third-border-end),

    var(--fill-color)                 var(--fourth-border-start),
    var(--fourth-circle-border-color) var(--fourth-border-position),
    var(--fill-color)                 var(--fourth-border-end)
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="circles-background">

</div>
```